# Встраиваемый сервер

Tags: java, сервер, jsp

Нужно в приложение встроить сервер (чтобы он мог отображать jsp).
Как это сделать, не используя tomcat и тому подобные штуки.
Есть ли какие-то библиотеки?
Гугл почти ничего не дал.

Comment: Jetty. [Пример проекта](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp)

Comment: @enzo, спасибо огромное. Правда, я его уже нашел до того, как вы ответили.